# How to display previous year totals into current year in Tableau??without creating parameter

Tags: tableau-api

I need to create a field of previous year total sales in the current year column.

Here is an example based on it being 2018 today: in 2018, it should be 2017 total sales(full year), in 2019, it should be 2018 Sales(jan-apr would be only months in may), and 2020 should be blank, as there are no data in 2019 yet, etc.

Comment: CAn you add dummy data

Answer (score 0):

Use the calculation to make it as "Date-1".

[image]

[image]